# Question regarding date of entry for form I-765

Tags: immigration

I am a US Citizen. My spouse who is a Vietnamese citizen in the US on an F-1 visa and I traveled to Canada for a day trip. She got an entry stamp into Canada but no stamp re-entering USA. The trip does not show in her I-94 online page.

Should we figure out the date and place of entry for the I-765 even though she has no stamp or I-94 info for it?

If we shouldn't, then what should we use for this.